# How get Key_down event without repeating?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

In want use keyboard like a musical keyboard - press a key for playing,  release the key for stop playing. Application is UWP and target platform is Windows 10 with normal hw keyboard. I try to do it with Key_down event. Here is test code (XAML page is empty, so only C# code):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace testKeyborad
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown -= CoreWindow_KeyDown;
        }

        private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"CoreWindow_KeyDown: {args.VirtualKey}  {args.KeyStatus.WasKeyDown} {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.ss}");
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm holding a key, the event is firing repeatedly. There is a workaround with *args.KeyStatus.WasKeyDown* which is *false* in the first event (it is shown in the code), but it is a strange way.

Is possible to get only one key_down event?

Comment: I would probably just have a flag that triggers when you press it down, and just handles all future event requests. then uncheck said flag when the key goes up.

Comment: `args.KeyStatus.WasKeyDown` seems like the way to go. Why don't you just ignore any events that have this set?

Comment: You could get complicated and detach the event on keydown, then it would not fire again and reattach it on keyup or use any other convoluted suggestion you will get :) But it seems `WasKeyDown` is intended to achieve what you are looking for so why not use it?

Comment: You can do `List<KeyCode> currentlyPressed = new List<KeyCode>()` and then in the `KeyDown` event `if(!currentlyPressed.Contains(e.KeyCode)) { currentlyPressed.Add(e.KeyCode); /*rest of the logic*/ }` and in `KeyUp` event `if(currentlyPressed.Contains(e.KeyCode)) currentlyPressed.Remove(e.KeyCode);`

Comment: Alternatively you could run this in a loop and check with `Keyboard.IsKeydown`.

Comment: Yes, @Manfred Radlwimmer, there is probably no better way then use the `KeyStatus.WasKeyDown`. It seems to me unbelievable that in UWP isn't _KeyDown_ as in WinForms, JavaScript, VBA, Turbo Pascal...

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you can use a flag, additionally you can suppress the key press if this flag is pressed, and use KeyUp to reset it.

```
    private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
    {
        if (KeyDown)
        {
           args.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
        else
        {
           Debug.WriteLine($"CoreWindow_KeyDown: {args.VirtualKey}  {args.KeyStatus.WasKeyDown} {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.ss}");
           KeyDown = true;
        }
    }

    public void CoreWindow_KeyUp(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
    {
       KeyDown = false;
    }
```

Comment: this wont work as intended. If you press let's assume `A` key and then press `B` key then you release `A` key it will catch both `A` and `B` but `B` after releasing `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Back when i used XNA and Monogame, the way to go was to store the last key pressed and compare with the new one pressed. I believe the same behaviour would work with your project. But i don't know if this is the best suited for your problem

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private Key _lastKeyPressed;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown -= CoreWindow_KeyDown;
        }

        private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
        {
            if(e.Key != _lastKeyPressed)
            {
                //do something
                Debug.WriteLine($"CoreWindow_KeyDown: {args.VirtualKey}  {args.KeyStatus.WasKeyDown} {DateTime.Now:mm:ss.ss}");
            }
            _lastKeyPressed = e.Key;
        }
    }
```